# Three-level hierarchical table structure

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

To achieve the result as shown in the sample image file from below response I wrote the the below logic - this gives me the correct result but I am facing one issue from above code:

When I click on child-table row it will not open the grand-child table.

Please suggest the fix or any other way to achieve this.

[image: example output]

```
example_data = [
    {
        "Approved": 0,
        "Denied": 1,
        "tat_avg": 0,
        "Name": "Total Care- PREFERRED",
        "Aetna": {
            "Approved": 0,
            "Denied": 1,
            "tat_avg": 0,
            "Name": "Aetna",
            "Humira": {
                "Approved": 0,
                "Denied": 1,
                "tat_avg": 0,
                "Name": "Humira"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Approved": 1,
        "Denied": 0,
        "tat_avg": 0,
        "Name": "Acaria Specialty Pharmacy",
        "test bin": {
            "Approved": 1,
            "Denied": 0,
            "tat_avg": 0,
            "Name": "test bin",
            "Aveed": {
                "Approved": 1,
                "Denied": 0,
                "tat_avg": 0,
                "Name": "Aveed"
            }
        }
    },
]
```

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ path('api_path') }}",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {enterpriseID:{{user.enterpriseID}}, tab: 'pharmacy_analysis', start: startdate, end: enddate},
    success: function (data) {
        pharmacy_analysis_data = example_data;

        // Destroy the existing DataTable if it already exists
        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#example1')) {
        $('#example1').DataTable().destroy();
        }

        // Initialize DataTable with new data
        let table1 = $('#example1').DataTable({
        data: pharmacy_analysis_data,
        scrollY: 500,
        paging: false,
        columns: [
            {
                data: null,
                className: 'dt-control',
                orderable: false,
                defaultContent: '',
            },
            { data: 'Name' },
            { data: 'Approved' },
            { data: 'Denied' },
            { data: 'tat_avg' }
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        language: {
            emptyTable: "No data available"
        }
        });
        
        table1.on('click', 'td.dt-control', function (e) {
        let tr = e.target.closest('tr');
        let row = table1.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.classList.remove('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(formatChild(row.data())).show();
            tr.classList.add('shown');
            var childTable = $(row.node()).next().find('.child-table');

            // Handle click events for child rows
            childTable.on('click', 'td.dt-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var childRow = childTable.DataTable().row(tr);
                console.log(childRow);
                console.log(childRow.data());
                if (childRow.child.isShown()) {
                    childRow.child.hide();
                    tr.classList.remove('shown');
                } else {
                    childRow.child(formatGrandChild(childRow.data())).show();
                    tr.classList.add('shown');
                }
            });
        }
        });

        function formatChild(data) {
        var childTable = '';

        // Check if the data has nested elements
        for (const key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof data[key] === 'object') {
                const subArray = data[key];
                childTable +=
                '<table class="child-table" style="width:100%">' +
                '<tr class="child-row">' +
                '<td class="child-dt-control dt-control"></td>' +
                '<td class="child-dt-control">' + subArray.Name + '</td>' +
                '<td class="child-dt-control">' + subArray.Approved + '</td>' +
                '<td class="child-dt-control">' + subArray.Denied + '</td>' +
                '<td class="child-dt-control">' + subArray.tat_avg + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';

                // If there are further nested elements, call formatGrandChild recursively
                childTable += formatGrandChild(subArray);
            }
        }

        return childTable;
        }

        function formatGrandChild(data) {
        var grandChildTable = '';

        // Check if the data has nested elements
        for (const key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof data[key] === 'object') {
                const subArray = data[key];
                grandChildTable +=
                    '<table class="grandchild-table" style="width:100%">' +
                    '<tr class="grandchild-row">' +
                    '<td class="grandchild-dt-control dt-control"></td>' +
                    '<td class="grandchild-dt">' + subArray.Name + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="grandchild-dt">' + subArray.Approved + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="grandchild-dt">' + subArray.Denied + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="grandchild-dt">' + subArray.tat_avg + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</table>';
            }
        }

        return grandChildTable;
        }
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
});
```

Comment: So, where is your question ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @MisterJojo please check my updated code.

Comment: I don't think nesting tables is a good idea, it unnecessarily complicates the css layout. And please, use the dedicated JS instructions to manage table elements! [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483596/improve-the-algorithm-for-reading-json-and-creating-a-table/77483949#77483949)

Comment: otherwise, I don't see why you insist on thinking that this is an AJAX problem?  except `data: { enterpriseID: { { user.enterpriseID } },` is certainly wrong...

Comment: @Akshay Well, as everyone is saying, this is a bad idea. A better approach can be creating the same structure in a ``<div></div>``. This is easier to manage and to make. The only difference you will have is the filter function, which can be adapted to the new structure.